# (set was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I've seen several articles about the error I'm getting, I just can't figure it out. If I answer 1-5 all works perfect.  If I answer 6 or 7 it gives the error:(set was unexpected at this time
Is it something wrong in my if statements?

```
:if
if %q1% == 1 (if %q2% == n (set sku=XG8ATCHUS) else set sku=XW8ATCHUS)
if %q1% == 2 (if %q2% == n (set sku=XG1ATCHUS) else set sku=XW1ATCHUS)
if %q1% == 3 (if %q2% == n (set sku=XG1BTCHUS) else set sku=XW1BTCHUS)
if %q1% == 4 (if %q2% == n (set sku=XG1CTCHUS) else set sku=XW1CTCHUS)
if %q1% == 5 (if %q2% == n (set sku=XG1DTCHUS) else set sku=XW1DTCHUS)
if %q1% == 6 set sku=XG21TCHUS
if %q1% == 7 set sku=XG23TCHUS
if %q3% == f set sku2=FullGuard
if %q3% == e set sku2=EnterpriseGuard
```

Comment: This happens when the variable `q2` is empty; use quotes to solve that; `if "%q2%" == "n" `)... By the way: do not use label names that are equal to commands (`:if`)...

Comment: That did it!  I would mark this as answered if it weren't a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation I use for this is

`if "%q1"=="1"`

and so on. This works if the parameters are empty, which is the problem in your case.